# Index scan when filtering on column calculated as DATEADD from column with clustered index

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing, dateadd

I'm puzzled why I'm getting clustered index seeks on query on calculated column that uses simple DATEADD function (that should be deterministic) over other column which is cluster indexed.

Am I able to keep the nonmaterialized calculated column (since this is for existing huge legacy data) and be able to filter by this column and have the sql hit the index? I need to filter on the calculated column (as I cannot change the queries and they need to query with proper offset).

Simplistic example definition:

```
-- table with calculated column
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_test](
    [Dt] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--clustered index
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [Idx] ON [dbo].[_test]
(
    [Dt] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



--simulation of legacy data
DECLARE @rdate DATE
DECLARE @startLoopID INT = 1
DECLARE @endLoopID INT = 1000

WHILE @startLoopID <= @endLoopID
BEGIN
    SET @rdate = DATEADD(Hour, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % (365 * 24) ), '2020-01-01');
    SET @startLoopID = @startLoopID + 1;

    INSERT INTO [_test] (Dt)
    VALUES (@rdate);
END

--adding the calculated column with proper offset
alter table _test ADD [Dt_2] AS  DATEADD(MINUTE, 300, Dt)
```

Example execution:
DECLARE @EndTime DATETIME2(7) = '2020-07-10 00:00:00.000'

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME2(7) = DATEADD(day, -12, @EndTime)

--select is performing seek
select * from _test
where 
 Dt > @StartTime AND Dt < @EndTime
 
--select is performing scan
select * from _test
where 
 Dt_2 > @StartTime AND Dt_2 < @EndTime
```

Query plan:

[image: Query Plan]

When filtering on `Dt` column I get expected seek. When filtering on `Dt_2` column - which is calculated from `Dt` via deterministic function - I get index scan.
In a real scenario with large amount of data this is causing huge performance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to index the calculated column in order for SQL to be able to perform a seek. The calculated column only gets evaluated at select-time unless it is persisted or indexed. Even if it was marked as `persisted`, it would still need to be scanned without an index. The fact that the expression is deterministic and precise means it *can* be indexed, but you still need to add the index.

Your comment below indicates you are unable to add an index to the computed column. But in this particular case, you don't actually need one anyway in order to perform the same query, because your calculated column is adding a constant offset to your original column. Therefore, the constant expression can be moved to the right hand side of the comparison operation in the query itself, and SQL will still be able to use the original clustered index.

That is to say, instead of creating a new column which is equal to `Dt` plus some constant, you can subtract the constant from the RHS of the inequality. Instead of:

```
alter table _test ADD [Dt_2] AS  DATEADD(MINUTE, 300, Dt);

DECLARE @EndTime DATETIME2(7) = '2020-07-10 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME2(7) = DATEADD(day, -12, @EndTime);

select * from _test
where 
 Dt_2 > @StartTime AND Dt_2 < @EndTime;
```

You can use:

```
--subtract 300 minutes from the @endTime parameter instead of adding 300 minutes to every value of Dt

DECLARE @EndTime DATETIME2(7) = dateadd(minute, -300, '2020-07-10 00:00:00.000');
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME2(7) = DATEADD(day, -12, @EndTime);

select * from _test
where 
 Dt > @StartTime
AND Dt < @EndTime;
```

Comment: This is a large table with legacy data - persisting the column would yield lengthy operation that we need to avoid.

Comment: If you can't add an index to the column, then there is nothing on which the engine will be able to seek.

Comment: @Jan I have edited my answer to give you a much simpler option

Comment: Yes, I'd love to do this, but unfortunately I cannot change the query (as mentioned in the question). The queries are generated by code that cannot be changed, I need them to hit the data with proper time offset.
I know - too many constraints:-/ - fun with legacy code..

Comment: Are you saying that there is *already* a query which references the `Dt_2` column? Sorry, I thought you intended to add the `Dt_2` column, and the existing legacy query was only referencing the `Dt` column - if that were true you wouldn't have to modify the legacy query, just change the input parameters. If you already have the `Dt_2` column, and you can't change that query, and you can't change the parameter values of the original query on `Dt`, *and* you can't add an index to the computed column, then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: The query references existing column with clustered index. We need to fix data for it, so without need to physically alter the data, we wanted to rename it and create calculated one with the same name.
We cannot alter the query.
We can potentially recalculate the backend data - but wanted to avoid the cost if possible

Comment: @Jan Yeah, I think you're a bit stuck there. Especially if you have any tables with foreign keys back to the existing `Dt` column, because you'd have to drop them all, then rename, then recreate, and changing the actual data in the existing `Dt` would require cascades, or drop foreign key, change data in foreign tables, change in `Dt`, recreate foreign keys. Painful.

Comment: Just to close the loop - we ended up with migrating the data to the new table (cheaper for large table with few columns)